# Is there existing cf-uaac for Windows?

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, predix

Ii was trying to work with Predix, so is there existing tools for Creating and Managing Users with the UAA CLI (UAAC, cf-uaac) for Windows users?

I know that https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-uaac/tree/master/lib existing solution for linux users, also i know about predix devBox.

Maybу possible way how to do it from Windows ?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `uaac` command you mention you can use the [Predix UAA dashboard](https://uaa-dashboard.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/#/login/) for a web console experience that can be helpful for quick one-off tasks.  There is also the [DevBox](https://www.predix.io/resources/tutorials/tutorial-details.html?tutorial_id=1466&tag=1607&journey=Development%20environment&resources=1466,1557,1574,1545) experience which can run a full linux environment with any Predix dev tools in a virtual machine.

Those options aside, the `cf-uaac` tool is a rubygem which means you must first install Ruby and make sure it is in your PATH.  The details for how to do that can be found on the [rubyinstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) site.  Once you've done that you should be able to follow the instructions on the [cf-uaac](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-uaac) project.

```
C:\Ruby> gem install cf-uaac
```

Hope that helps get you going.

Comment: Once you've installed cf-uaac how do you run it ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to download, predix devbox refering to the below link
https://www.predix.io/services/other-resources/devbox.html

you need a Oracle VM installed and the you can import this devbox file
it is a local environment which has everything setup you don't need to concentrate on configuration things and your development would be boosted.

Also in the above question you mentioned about tools for creation and management of users, the answer is yes predix has come up with UAA dashboard
which ease management
https://uaa-dashboard.run.aws-usw02-pr.ice.predix.io/#/login

Answer (score -1):

Thank you, so first of all i have to setup Ruby (that's why gem will be work). After installing Ruby we need to instal Ruby DevBox, than configure it and only after that - "gem install cf-uaac" will be work. So thanks so you help (i don't know that Ruby is required for uaac.